# Extract certain data from multiple XML files into excel

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I have over a 1000 XML files, all with different data, but the same tags

```
<Title>
    <LocalTitle>12 Years a Slave</LocalTitle>
    <OriginalTitle>12 Years a Slave</OriginalTitle>
    <ProductionYear>2013</ProductionYear>
    <Added>23/05/2015 15:42:03</Added>
    <IMDBrating>8,1</IMDBrating>
    <ContentRating>R</ContentRating>
    <MPAARating>R</MPAARating>
    <IMDB>tt2024544</IMDB>
    <IMDbId>tt2024544</IMDbId>
    <TMDbId>76203</TMDbId>
    <Budget>20000000</Budget>
    <Revenue>187</Revenue>
    <Language>English</Language>
    <LanguageCode>en</LanguageCode>
    <Country>GB</Country>
    <RunningTime>134</RunningTime>
    <Overview>In the antebellum United States,</Overview>
    <Genres>
        <Genre>Biography</Genre>
        <Genre>Drama</Genre>
        <Genre>History</Genre>
    </Genres>
</Title>
```

I only need to extract certain tags from all my XML files into an excel file (like only the `LocalTitle`, `ProductionYear`, `IMDBRating` and `IMDBId`) How can I do this without spending hours copy-ing and pasting?

Comment: Your could extract them with an XSLT to create a CSV file which could be imported to Excel.

Comment: I just tried the XSLT but with no success, any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Re-consider XSLT. And Excel VBA's [MSXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759204%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object maintains an XSLT 1.0 processor. Additionally, Excel can import the transformed XML directly into workbooks with the [OpenXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838643.aspx) method:

**XSLT** *(save externally as .xsl to be called below; returns only needed tags)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="Title">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="LocalTitle|ProductionYear|IMDBrating|IMDbId"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**VBA**

```
Public Sub XSLTransform()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    ' ADD MSXML v6.0 REFERENCE '
    Dim xmldoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim xslDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60 
    Dim newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim newwkb As Workbook

    ' LOAD XML AND XSL FILES '
    xslDoc.async = False
    xmldoc.Load "C:\Path\To\Input.xml"

    xslDoc.async = False
    xslDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\XSLTScript.xsl"

    ' TRANSFORM XML '
    xmldoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
    newDoc.Save "C:\Path\To\Output.xml"

    ' IMPORT TRANSFORMED XML '
    Set newwkb = Workbooks.OpenXML("C:\Path\To\Output.xml", , xlXmlLoadImportToList)

    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Err.Raise xslDoc.parseError.ErrorCode, , xslDoc.parseError.reason
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

**XML** Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Title>
    <LocalTitle>12 Years a Slave</LocalTitle>
    <ProductionYear>2013</ProductionYear>
    <IMDBrating>8,1</IMDBrating>
    <IMDbId>tt2024544</IMDbId>
</Title>
```